# Where to publish a first article in Deep Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, papers, research

What would be examples of journals that are good for a **first publication** in the field of Deep Reinforcement Learning?

I am in the process of writing about the research results of DQN-related algorithms.

I have 3 requirements - it should be indexed in one of these databases, otherwise, I cannot receive grant money for research:

- https://www.scopus.com/
- http://webofknowledge.com

And it should not be very expensive to publish. It should be under 1000EUR to publish, for example, the Open Access license for Elsevier "Artificial Intelligence" journal costs around 2400EUR to publish.

And it should not have a very long review/publishing period. For example, Elsevier's "Information Fusion" journal currently gathers articles for July 2018, which is 8 month period till publishing. Is it normal?

Can you please recommend some journals that qualify & you have had good experience publishing research?

Answer (score 6):

One important consideration here: in the last decade or two the machine learning and artificial intelligence fields, which contains the majority of reinforcement learning work, researchers have considered **conferences to be the more impactful publishing venues than journals**. The particular venue a researcher chooses depends on the data and/or application domain of his or her use of reinforcement learning, and the conferences are often changing, but to get you started the top tier conferences are (in rough order of exclusivity and importance):

- [ICML](https://icml.cc/)
- [NeurIPS](https://nips.cc/)
- [ICLR](https://iclr.cc/)
- [AAAI](http://www.aaai.org/)
- [IJCAI](https://www.ijcai.org/)
- [RLDM](http://rldm.org/)
- [UAI](http://www.auai.org/) (more theory driven)
- [AISTATS](https://www.aistats.org/) (more theory driven)
- [COLT](http://learningtheory.org/colt2020/) (more theory driven)
- [CoRL](https://www.robot-learning.org/) (robotics focus)
- [RSS](https://roboticsconference.org/) (robotics focus)
- [ICRA](https://www.icra2020.org/) (robotics focus)
- [IROS](http://www.iros2020.org/) (robotics focus)
- [CVPR](http://cvpr2020.thecvf.com/) (visual data focus)
- [ECCV](https://eccv2020.eu/)/[ICCV](http://iccv2019.thecvf.com/) (visual data focus)
- [EMNLP](https://2020.emnlp.org/) (language focus)
- [ACL](https://acl2020.org/) (language focused)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you focus on quality over quantity. Publishing a paper will boost your reputation and make you more recognised within your academic field (AI); however, this is only if the paper provides useful insights into an important issue.

Your paper is more likely to be accepted if it is well written and easy to understand, stimulates new important questions, uses rigorous methods to explain why the data supports the conclusion and connections to prior work is made and serve to make your paper's arguments clear. (Elizabeth Z Elsevier blog)

Before submitting your paper, ask a mentor or a colleague to proofread it, so that you can make the relevant revisions and changes. Journal editors will look down on your work if it is poorly written or contains substandard grammar.

A way to get published is by writing reviews, especially for researchers in earlier stages of their careers. Most journal editors like to publish replies to previous publications since it stimulates debate.

Remember it is acceptable to challenge reviewers' suggestions with good justification. Many researchers fail to persevere when they are instructed to revise and resubmit their work. Don't give up, however, you can politely decline or even argue why a reviewer is wrong. Editors will accept a rational explanation if it is clear that you have considered all their feedback.

Getting published is never easy, especially in high ranking journals. If you focus on getting published quickly it could derail you from concentrating on the quality of your research. Yes, getting published can be expensive, however, it's much better for your career if you write a high-quality paper than a low-quality paper in a lowly ranked or ungraded journal since it will not be REFable.

Below is a list of Artificial Intelligence Journals that you can submit your papers to and possibly get published.

- Artificial Intelligence (Journal) https://www.journals.elsevier.com/artificial-intelligence
- Artificial Intelligence Review  https://link.springer.com/journal/10462
- Applied Artificial Intelligence http://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=uaai20&
- Autonomous Agents and Multi-Agent Systems  https://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/10458
- International Journal on Artificial Intelligence Tools http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscinet/ijait
- International Journal of Pattern Recognition and Artificial Intelligence http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscinet/ijprai
- Journal of Experimental and Theoretical Artificial Intelligence  http://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=teta20
- Journal of Machine Learning Research  http://www.jmlr.org/
- IEEE Intelligent Systems  http://publications.computer.org/intelligent-systems/
- Journal of Automated Reasoning  https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/journal/10817
- Minds and Machines  https://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/11023
- Autonomous Agents and Multi-Agent Systems  https://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/10458
- Applied Intelligence  https://link.springer.com/journal/10489
- Journal of Intelligent Manufacturing  https://link.springer.com/journal/10845
- Journal of Intelligent Information Systems   https://link.springer.com/journal/10844
- AI & Society  https://link.springer.com/journal/146